# Deep explanation of the conversion of a simple array into two-dimensional array (matrix) with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a conceptive explanation regarding one of the parts of the function that I will post below.

I discovered the following solution for a problem:

```
let argh = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];


function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var matrix = [], i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % size === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
        }

        matrix[k].push(arr[i]);

        i //returns: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        k //returns: 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2
    }

    return matrix;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(argh,2))
//result: [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

The point is not the solution itself, as this function works as it should.

What I need is an explanation about exactly how does `k` iterate with `i`.

As you can see above, `k` returned `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2`. Visually, I understand that the numbers pushed into `matrix[k]` get distributed as two numbers on each value that `k` is returning (2 numbers pushed when `k` is `0`, creating an `array` and so on...)

What I need to understand is:

1. Why isn't `k` returning just the amount of times that the `if` code returned `true`, returning just `0,1,2`?
2. I know that each time `k` returns, it is equivalent to each `array` that will be created. How does this iteration of each time the digit repeating itself turns into the way that the numbers will be distributed into the arrays?

I can't get this into my head.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Use a google based browser on a pc or firefox. Hit F12. Now you can track down what it does. step by step A piece of knowledge is also found by the documentation of the Array.push() function. If you are so clever to ask here you will also be able (by little more own afford) to track this thing down.

Comment: `k` increases by one every `size` iterations of `i`

Comment: @Bravo I see...Thanks for the explanation. You've got the core of my doubt. So it increases regardless if the statement is true or not on each iteration in the ```if``` statement?

Comment: no, `k` increases **when** the if statement is true, in other words, when `i` is a multiple of `size` (including 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can understand in the following steps

- Initially k is `-1` and `i = 0`

  - so `i % size === 0` will be true for first iteration as `0 % 2 => 0`
  - inside loop we increment k by `1` so no it is `k = 1`
- Now on second iteration `i = 1, k = 0`

  - `i % size === 0` will be false because `1 % 2 => 1`
  - So we don't go into `if` block and `k` will remain as `1`

---

And i is incremented irrespective of any condition so on every iteration you see a increase by `1`

---

> Why isn't k returning just the amount of times that the if code
>   returned true, returning just 0,1,2 ?

If you're printing outside it doesn't depend how many time `if` statement returns true it prints the value of `k`, you can add the console inside `if` if you need to print only when it returns true

---

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand that ```k``` will increase, in this case, from ```-1``` to ```2```, creating ```3``` arrays. What I still would like to understand is why ```k``` returns a length that is equal to ```i``` on the block code that I've posted above. When ```if``` is ```false``` ```k``` does not increase, but it repeats its self, adding up to the same length as ```i```. I don't understand this. The result  of ```k``` in that part of the block of code is a visual way of seeing the distribution of ```[i]``` pushed in to ```matrix[k]```.

Comment: @Alioshr because you're iterating `arr.length-1` times over the values, so if you console anything `arr.length-1` time will display `arr.length-1` time only, as the loggin is out of conditional block so it doesn't care whether the value of `k` is same as last or not. if you need `k` to be `0,1,2` you log it inside `if` statement